# Deploying one solution with multiple projects to one Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureportal, webjob

I have created a WebJob in Azure that receives and aggregates/stores data from a sensor. At first (when I only had one project in my solution), I just ran `dotnet build -c Release` and uploaded those build files to the Azure Portal. That worked fine.

Eventually I started to change the folder structure etc so now the solution has 3 projects, with one startup project (ReceiverWebJob). See below:

[image]

How can I deploy those 3 projects in just **one** Azure WebJob?

**UPDATE**: According to @Harshitha, It is still possible to use the `dotnet build -c Release` command. I tried this and uploaded the created files from every project's `bin/Release/net6.0` folder. The WebJob now runs without any problems.

**UPDATE 2**: Also according to @Harshitha it should also be possible to use an Azure Pipeline for App Service Deployment tasks. I will try this when I have finished my feature.

Comment: Whayt is the framework of the Projects.Are you using `Console App` ?

Comment: To run a `WebJob`, you need to create a Console App.

Comment: Create a blank solution and add 3 projects in it.Zip the 3 projectsinto a single folder using `dotnet build -c Release` and upload in the Azure App Service `WebJobs`.

Comment: We can also use `Azure App Service Deploy task` in Azure Pipeline to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Harshitha, thanks for your help. The ReceiverWebJob project is a Console Application in .NET 6. It uses/has references to the Core and Infrastructure project. 

If I want to use the `dotnet build -c Release` command, do I then zip those 3 projects completely or just the files inside their `bin/Release/net6.0` folders?

Also: is this the Pipeline you mean? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v4?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Run `dotnet build -c Release` on each individual project seperately, then copy the contents from bin folder of all the 3 projects to a single directory, then zip those folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below steps to run multiple projects in a single `Azure WebJob`.

- Create a Console Application.As you have  mentioned  I have taken `.NET 6` Console Application.
- With in the same Application add 2 new projects.
- Navigate to each project root directory and run the `dotnet build -c Release` command on each individual Application.

[image]

- Application will be compiled and dlls will be created in a `release` folder.

[image]

- Now combine all the files generated  in a release folder into a new directory. Zip that folder.
- Create a new `Azure App Service`.
- Select `WebJobs` under `Settings` of the `App Service` and add a new `WebJob`.
- Browse the zipped folder and add a new `Web Job`.

[image]